# dynamic plotbands in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, dynamic, highcharts

I need to highlight the (whole) current column band when I move the mouse over a HighChart chart. I have obtained this using dynamic plot bands as follows (JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gftp584y/), an adaption from a basic demo chart):

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        xAxis: {
            plotBands: [{from:1,to:1}],
        },
        plotOptions:{
        series: {
          point: {
            events: {
                mouseOver: function () {moveBand(this.index);}
            }
          }
        }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

        }]
    });

function moveBand(a) {
var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
chart.xAxis[0].update({plotBands:[{color: '#f0c0c0',from:a-0.5,to:a+0.5}]});
}    
});
```

Since this solution is a bit slow in my real chart (which contains several dozens of points and several series) I ask if this is the best way to satisfy my need or there is a better solution.

Comment: How about using something like crosshair? http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic

Comment: I missed it! Please make your comment an answer so I can vote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable crosshair on the xAxis.

```
xAxis: {
    crosshair: true
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/da70aofL/